# Data usage on flutter

Tags: flutter, android-data-usage

So I am working on a flutter app for streaming, however it's data consumption seems crazy. Just to load the home screen with just thumbnails and titles, it consumes about 12.4 mb and if reloading that, doubles that amount.

Is there a way to optimise the app to consume less data or it is simply reducing the image qualities and hope to get the best data performance out of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A flutter library to show images from the internet and keep them in
> the cache directory.

```
dependencies:
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
```

---

```
CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

It will reduce the time